# asp.net apache2/nginx OutputCache problem

Tags: asp.net, linux, mono, nginx, outputcache

I have a problem regarding the outputcache settings in web.config file.
I am using Nginx 0.8.53 with Fast CGI, on openSuse 11.3

For dynamic pages, I created OutputCacheProfiles which are working perfectly on visual studio environment in windows. When I request a page, it comes with the correct cache-control header. But when I am working with Nginx on openSuse, it keeps sending "Cache-Control public, max-age=0" no matter what I set in OutputCacheProfiles. I tried apache2, it also seems to be not responding the outputcacheprofile settings as in nginx.

Everything works perfectly on windows environment, I get the correct cache-control headers for different pages in different browsers. But when I am using apache or nginx it seems to be not responding to my outputcacheprofiles in web.config file.
    I deleted  directive with its content, it still adds that max-age=0 on responses. 
    Hope I explained the situation.
    Best regards.

```
<caching>
  <outputCache enableOutputCache="true" />
  <outputCacheSettings>
    <outputCacheProfiles>
        <add name="MatchesController.Index" duration="5" varyByParam="*" varyByCustom="utcOffset" location="ServerAndClient" enabled="true" noStore="true"/>
        <add name="MatchesFeedController.Index" duration="5" varyByParam="*" varyByCustom="utcOffset" location="ServerAndClient" enabled="true" noStore="true"/>
        <add name="MatchesFeedController.IncidentsSummary" duration="5" varyByParam="*" location="ServerAndClient" enabled="true"/>
        <add name="MatchesController.Show" duration="60" varyByParam="*" varyByCustom="utcOffset" location="ServerAndClient" enabled="true"/>
        <add name="MatchesController.Preview" duration="60" varyByParam="*" varyByCustom="utcOffset" location="ServerAndClient" enabled="true"/>
        <add name="MatchesController.Live" duration="60" varyByParam="*" varyByCustom="utcOffset" location="ServerAndClient" enabled="true"/>
        <add name="MatchesController.TeamStats" duration="60" varyByParam="*" varyByCustom="utcOffset" location="ServerAndClient" enabled="true"/>
    </outputCacheProfiles>
  </outputCacheSettings>
</caching>
```

Answer (score 0):

Sounds more like a mono bug than an nginx/apache issue. When using mono, try to use the xsp webserver that ships with mono to host your application without using nginx or apache, and check the results of the `Cache-Control` headers. If they are wrongly set to `public, max-age=0` even without nginx/apache in between, this might be a bug in mono.